# Dynamically display checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, mysql, checkbox, checkboxlist

On my web page I have 2 text boxes which take the input as Year and month respectively. Then From the Database table depending on these values a column value is retrieved which is called working days. Its value is in this format(111110011111001111100111110011) Here 1 mean Working days and 0 means a holiday(can be sat or sun or any other holiday). Now depending on this retrieved value i want to display 30/31(depending on month days) check boxes and the holidays check boxes should be checked and remaining unchecked. It should be like this
1 2 3 4 5 6 7...............................30 
and check boxes beneath them. Now the code am using displays only 1 checkbox beneath 1(which is the first header) and then the next dates are shown in the repeater but the checkboxes appear in the next line. can you tell me the problem?

Code Behind

> public class MyCheckBox
>           {
>               public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
>           }
>
> ```
>     public void search(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>        string cnnString = "Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=leavesystem;Uid=root;Pwd=ashish";
>         MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
>         cnx.Open();
>         string cmdText = "Select WorkingDays from calender where Year = '" + year.Value + "' and Month = '" + month.Value + "' ";
>         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);
>         if (month.Value == " January || March || May || July || August || October || December ")
>         {
>             string str = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
>             List<MyCheckBox> list = new List<MyCheckBox>();
>             foreach (char c in str)
>                 list.Add(new MyCheckBox { IsChecked = c == '0' });
>             MyRepeater1.DataSource = list;
>             MyRepeater1.DataBind();
>         }
>         else if (month.Value == " April || June || September || November ")
>         {
>             string str = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
>             List<MyCheckBox> list = new List<MyCheckBox>();
>             foreach (char c in str)
>                 list.Add(new MyCheckBox { IsChecked = c == '0' });
>             MyRepeater2.DataSource = list;
>             MyRepeater2.DataBind();
>         }
>         else if (month.Value == " February ")
>         {
>             string str = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
>             List<MyCheckBox> list = new List<MyCheckBox>();
>             foreach (char c in str)
>                 list.Add(new MyCheckBox { IsChecked = c == '0' });
>             MyRepeater3.DataSource = list;
>             MyRepeater3.DataBind();
>         }
>
> }
> ```

The repeater looks like this

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server">
>                       <HeaderTemplate>
>                              <table width="100%" class="table" border="1" style="font: 8pt verdana">
>                                <tr>
>                                      <%
>                                           for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
>                                                   {
>                                                           Response.Write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
>                                                   }    
>                                      %>
>                               </tr>
>             
>                      </HeaderTemplate>
>                       <ItemTemplate>
>                               <tr> 
>                                 <td>
>                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked='<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>' runat="server" />
>                                 </td>
>                              </tr>
>                             </table>  
>                     </ItemTemplate>
>       </asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater2" runat="server">
           <HeaderTemplate>
               <table width="100%" class="table" border="1" style="font: 8pt verdana">
                    <tr>
                       <% for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
                          {
                              Response.Write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
                          } %>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked='<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>' runat="server" />
                    </td>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <FooterTemplate>
                    </tr>
               </table>
           </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>

       <asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater3" runat="server">
           <HeaderTemplate>
               <table width="100%" class="table" border="1" style="font: 8pt verdana">
                    <tr>
                       <% for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
                          {
                              Response.Write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
                          } %>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked='<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>' runat="server" />
                    </td>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <FooterTemplate>
                    </tr>
               </table>
           </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Did you see that my answer was correct?

Comment: Hey man I tried it but its showing just 1 checkbox. The answer given by ojlovecd shows all the checkboxes but vertically. I want them as a column member with column name as date. 1,2 ... so on.. can you edit the answer and help me with this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you another answer.
First you define a class, representing the checkbox is checed or not.

```
public class MyCheckBox
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Then, populate the list:

```
string cnnString = "Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=leavesystem;Uid=root;Pwd=ashish";

MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
cnx.Open();
string cmdText = "Select WorkingDays from calender where Year = '" + year.Value + "' and Month = '" + month.Value + "' ";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);

string str = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
List<MyCheckBox> list = new List<MyCheckBox>();
foreach (char c in str)
    list.Add(new MyCheckBox { IsChecked = c == '1' });
MyRepeater.DataSource = list;
MyRepeater.DataBind();
```

finally, the repeater looks like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <%
            for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                Response.Write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            }    
        %>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked='<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>' runat="server" />
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server"><HeaderTemplate><table width="100%" class="table" border="1" style="font: 8pt verdana"><tr><% for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++){Response.Write("<td>" + i + "</td>");} %></tr><tr></HeaderTemplate><ItemTemplate><td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked='<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>' runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </tr>
                  </table>  
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

Comment: Hey man am stuck with another problem.If there are 30 check boxes and 8 of them are checked which show that they are Saturday and Sunday now If I want to add another holiday here then I check the chechbox and press the update button so the query should take the pattern from the checkboxes and update it in the database. Suppose the pattern is 111110011111001111100111110011 . This is a month with 30 days. Now I check the box which is on the 3rd position so the pattern should be 110110011111001111100111110011. This should be updated in the database. What should I do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use DataSet here since you only need one value.

```
string cnnString = "Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=leavesystem;Uid=root;Pwd=ashish";

MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
cnx.Open();
string cmdText = "Select WorkingDays from calender where Year = '" + year.Value + "' and Month = '" + month.Value + "' ";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);

char[] a = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToCharArray();
ListItem[] items = new ListItem[a.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    items[i] = new ListItem(m.ToString());
    if (m == '0')
        items[i].Selected = true;
    else
        items[i].Selected = false;
    checks.Items.Add(items[i]);
    i++;
}
cnx.Close();
```

Comment: you answer is correct. but it shows the checkboxes vertically. How to display them in 1 line? I mean horizontally!!

Comment: @AshishBatra you can add a style to each checkbox: style="float:left;"

Comment: Hey man I have updated the question. Can you see the way I want the data. Here it is not shown properly. Actually i am using a repeater and the columns names should be the date names. Like 1, 2 till 30 and then beneath each column name only 1 checkbox which represent if this date is holiday or not. Can you make it in that format ?

Comment: <table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>....<td>30</td></tr><tr><asp:Repeater>your item template here</asp:Repeater></tr></table>

Comment: Hey man I did that and then in
 <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WorkingDays")%>
               </td>
               </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
What should I add in data binder so that checkboxes come under the columns

Comment: remove the <tr> from your <ItemTemplate>. See carefully my code. The repeater is inside the <tr>